# Flink JobManager HA on EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-flink, amazon-emr, high-availability

Stack
EMR: emr-6.1.0 (1 master, 4 core nodes)
EMR installed apps: FLINK 1.11.0

AWS documentation says (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/flink-configure.html):

```
Beginning with Amazon EMR version 5.28.0, JobManager high availability is also enabled automatically. No manual configuration is needed.
```

But when i send kill signal to Flink jobmanager `yarn container -signal container_1601027657994_0003_01_000001 GRACEFUL_SHUTDOWN` (same with `FORCEFUL_SHUTDOWN`) yarn container nothing happens. Yarn won't restart the app.

1. Do i need to enable EMR Zookeeper as well ? (most probably yes, otherwise, I don’t understand how flink will understand from which savepoint to restart the application).
2. Should i use a EMR cluster with 3 master nodes to have HA for Flink?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, to have an JobManager HA you need to have an EMR with 3 master nodes, and then emr automatically adds failover configuration into `flink-conf.yaml` (tested with EMR 6.1.0)